# Detect changes in one ref and write in another Firebase Cloud

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying **Firebase Cloud Functions** in my app using this code to remove data after 2 hours of created.

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/Rooms/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestampCreated/timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

This works. Now I want to write in another **ref** (for example: /Users/{userID}/) **every time data is deleted**. Regards

Comment: What's the problem you have with implementing that requirement?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, the problem is that I don't know how to write the promise because the examples I saw always made the modification in the same ref stated above (exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/Rooms/{pushId}') for example). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want the update to run as the current user or as an administrator, you can use `event.data.ref` or `event.data.adminRef` and work from there:

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/Rooms/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  ...
  var ref = event.data.ref.root;
  return ref.child("/Users/123").set("New value");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

things have changed on version 1.0, `adminRef` is deprecated, you should use just `ref` for admin access and `event` has been substituted by `snapshot` and `context`, see here: [cloud functions documentation 1.0 API changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

Frank's example becomes:

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/Rooms/{pushId}')
.onWrite((snapshot,context) => {
  ...
  var ref = snapshot.ref.root;
  return ref.child("/Users/123").set("New value");
});
```